# POSIX getline() - line buffer state on EOF?

Tags: c, posix, getline

This question is in regards to the POSIX C function [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html).

The documentation states that `getline` returns -1 on error (including EOF), but it doesn't say what becomes of `lineptr` or `n` in those situations.
I understand that some errors may be handled differently - such as a failed `realloc` - but what about EOF?  Do `lineptr` and `n` still retain their original values?  Is it implementation specific?  Undefined behavior?

Answer (score 5):

If getline return an error (EOF is an error in this function). The data in the buffer should not be used.

`EOF` must not be returned if the function reads at least 1 byte, note that the function can return 0 in some case.

Additionally, the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) clearly say:

> This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

---

> In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated
>   to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

This sentence could be interpreted as the buffer is only updated on a successful call.

---

In my opinion, the program should log this error and continue with the data that has been already read. Note: Use [`feof()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/feof) to know if the stream has reached the end.

Comment: I agree that the buffer should be freed when `getline` fails but that still doesn't say anything about the state of the buffer's contents on failure.  Either way, it doesn't sound like accessing the buffer after a `-1` return is well defined, so it's probably best that I don't depend on it.

Comment: @Mr.Llama By the way, I don't really understand why you want to know that for `EOF`. Why do you want to keep the data in the buffer that you have already parsed when `getline()` return without error? After thinking about that, this look like a XY problem.

Comment: I have a single line buffer and I'd like to print the final whole line before EOF.  The problem is that if `getline` returns -1 for EOF, I have no guarantees that my line buffer is still valid for printing.  Right now I'm working around it by using two line buffers.

Comment: The GNU docs https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html say "If an error occurs or end of file is reached without any bytes read, getline returns -1. " which seems to me to imply that even if the last line does not end with a newline, the function will return the number of chars read (and not -1). On the other hand the Linux docs don't say this, so maybe you should create a text file where the last line doesn't end with a newline and test what happens.

Comment: @Stuart The man say this too: "The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.".

Comment: @Stargateur I meant man does not say what happens if the last line does not end with a newline.

Comment: Yes, it is. I quote you the line! Read it twice.

Comment: @Stargateur read the POSIX docs (see my answer below). "Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition). " does not necessarily mean that what you think, because reading a line without a newline is not a "failure to read a line". If the last line does not end with a newline getline will return it's contents normally, and then return -1 on the next call.

Comment: @Stuart That's what I say, I never say the contrary. We agree. I don't understand why you tell me that... "`EOF` must not be returned if the function reads at least 1 byte, note that the function can return 0 in some case."

Answer (score 3):

If you look at these POSIX docs http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html
you will see that the function does not return -1 if it reads the last line in the stream and the EOF occurs without a newline (i.e. the last line does not have a newline). So when you reach EOF, the contents of the buffer don't matter because getline will not have written anything into it.

Comment: "So when you reach EOF" is probably more clearly understood as something like "So when the function returns -1 because of EOF" as EOF can be reached even when bytes are read and written to the buffer.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune yes, that is probably better, although the POSIX docs  say it pretty clearly. I probably shouldn't have tried to explain the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The values of `lineptr` and `n` are implementation-specific.  The getline() function might or might not reallocate the buffer when it reads EOF.

I point to Illumos, NetBSD, and FreeBSD as examples.  I look at getdelim() because all 3 systems have getline() call getdelim() with delimiter '\n'.

- [Illumos getdelim()](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/23a1ccea6aac035f084a7a4cdc968687d1b02daf/usr/src/lib/libc/port/stdio/getline.c) always tries for a buffer of at least 128 bytes, before it calls `__filbuf` to read the file.  So, if you pass in `*lineptr = NULL` and it reads EOF, you get back `*n = 128` and `*lineptr` pointing to 128 bytes of garbage.
- [NetBSD getdelim()](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdio/getdelim.c?rev=1.14&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN) always calls `__srefill` to read the file, before it tries any reallocation.  If it reads EOF, you get back the same `*lineptr` that you passed in.  If you passed in `*lineptr = NULL`, NetBSD does set `*n = 0`.
- [FreeBSD getdelim()](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdio/getdelim.c?revision=320472&view=markup) also reads before reallocating, but if it reads EOF, then it puts a single '\0' (for the empty string) in the buffer.  If `*lineptr` was NULL, FreeBSD allocates a 1-byte buffer.  This is different from NetBSD and Illumos, because those systems don't put an empty string in the buffer.

In conclusion, when getline() reads EOF, the value of `*lineptr` might or might not change, and it might or might not point to an empty string.